# SQL Server: CASE BETWEEN error, incorrect syntax near the keyword 'BETWEEN'

Tags: sql-server, case, between

I get the following error, when I'm trying to put ages into brackets. If I write the following the query goes well, but the brackets are mostly "not known" of course.

```
SELECT 
    ID,
    CASE age
       WHEN 40 THEN 'YOUNG'
       WHEN 50 THEN 'OLD'
       ELSE 'Not known'
    END as brackets
FROM table1
```

If I change the query to more suitable, as below, I get the error on topic. I wonder whats the clue.

```
SELECT 
    ID, 
    CASE age
        WHEN BETWEEN 18 AND 40 THEN 'young'
        WHEN BETWEEN 41 AND 99 THEN 'old'
        ELSE 'Not known'
    END as brackets
FROM table1
```

Comment: You would need to move age to each case. When age between 18 and 40...

Answer (score 7):

You should do it like this:

```
SELECT ID, 
CASE 
     WHEN age BETWEEN 18 AND 40 THEN 'young'
     WHEN age BETWEEN 41 AND 99 THEN 'old'
     ELSE 'Not known'
END as brackets
FROM table1
```